# Convert Back to BBCode from HTML When Editing

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am able to convert text from BBCode to HTML just fine, but let's say I want to edit the code on the page it shows up with the HTML tags instead of the BBCode when editing in a `<textarea>` using AJAX.

Say for example I submit `[b]bold text[/b]` and save it to my database. The page will show it as **bold text**. When I try to edit that on the page it comes up as `<strong>bold text</strong>` and then when I save it, it gets ride of the HTML tags because I am using `htmlspecialchars()`.

To convert from BBCode to HTML I use this:

```
$search = array (
    '/(\[b\])(.*?)(\[\/b\])/',
    '/(\[i\])(.*?)(\[\/i\])/',
    '/(\[u\])(.*?)(\[\/u\])/',
    '/(\[ul\])(.*?)(\[\/ul\])/',
    '/(\[li\])(.*?)(\[\/li\])/',
    '/(\[user=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/user\])/',
    '/(\[quote\])(.*?)(\[\/quote\])/',
    '/(\[code\])(.*?)(\[\/code\])/'
);

$replace = array (
    '<strong>$2</strong>',
    '<em>$2</em>',
    '<u>$2</u>',
    '<ul>$2</ul>',
    '<li>$2</li>',
    '<a href="../login/profile?u=$2" target="_blank">$2</a>',
    '<quote>$2</quote>',
    '<code>$2</code>'
);

$string = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

The string is whatever the text that is pulled from the database.

What I want is for the BBCode to display in the textarea so if it needs editing there is BBCode in place instead of HTML tags.

This is what the AJAX looks like with comments to help you understand it:

```
$('#editPost').click(function() { //Button used to edit posts
    $('#editablePost').val($('#post').html()); //Textarea gets the post html
    $('#editablePost').show(); //The textarea is hidden until needed
    $('#post').hide(); //Hides original post
    $('#editablePost').focus(); //Focuses on the textarea
});

$('#savePost').click(function() { //Button used to save posts
    $('#post').html($('#editablePost').val()); //Post gets the value of textarea
    $('#editablePost').hide(); //Hides the textarea
    $('#post').show(); //Shows post with new text in it
    // Code below is what I use to send the information to the database and update
    $detail = $('#post').text();
    $edit = $('#editPostTime').text();
    $id = $('#questionId').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'editPost.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {detail: $detail, edit: $edit, id: $id},
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function() {
            <?php
            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
            $datetime = date("d/m/y H:i"); // create date and time
            ?>
            $('#editPostTime').text('Edited: <?php echo $datetime; ?>'); //Updates on page when post was edited
    }});
});
```

I hope this isn't too long winded, I tried to be as thorough as possible though.

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to save BBcode in database, and only convert it when you need to output it as HTML.

Comment: That's what it does, the database stores the code with BBCode in it then converts to HTML when on the page.

Comment: There's not enough code to know that. What is preventing you from setting the BBcode as the textarea's value ?

Answer (score 0):

Just had a brainwave!

In the textarea that I am hiding, I just insert the original code that's not converted to HTML in it and it works!